# how to eliminate mutiple row with different values from oracle database using only SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have columns as below

```
----------------------------
brandb     model       class
nokia     x2            2nd
nokia    lumina         1st
sony    xperia          1st
sony    xperial        2nd 
sumsun   deo1          1st
sumsun   deo2          1st
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

o/p

```
sunsun deo1    1st
sumsun deo2    1st
```

---

I want to remove the brands NOKIA brand and sony  completely if it contains 2nd class row product from ORACLE SQL query.

many thanks in advance

Comment: HINT: DELETE ... WHERE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to delete the rows from the table, then you can try:

```
delete from table
    where brandb in (select t2.brandb from table t2 where t2.class = '2nd');
```

If you just want to return a query without those models:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.brandb not in (select t2.brandb from table t2 where t2.class = '2nd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from mytable
where brandb in (
    select brandb from myable
    where class ='2nd')
```